# how are 'requests' on Twitter Premium Archive get counted?

Tags: api, twitter, rtweet

I had bought Twitter historical archive subscription for 250 requests. After sending out only few requests, it said that I have exhausted my 250 requests while my tweet quota is still left. Could somebody please help me understand how does Twitter accounts for requests? I feel very shortchanged right now. There's no explanation anywhere on the site.

[image]

Comment: This shows that you’ve called the Twitter API with 262 individual requests (queries). That’s the limit. If you are using rTweet there is a [known bug](https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/368) where it unfortunately consumes too many requests too quickly.

Comment: Oh thanks, Andy. That's really helpful.